# How can I improve my PyTorch implementation of ResNet for CIFAR-10 classification?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, resnet

I have recently started to study the neural networks. I've got good results on MNIST with MLP and decided to write a classifier for CIFAR-10 dataset using CNN. I've chosen ResNet architecture to implement and tried to follow the wellknown article "Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognition": [it is here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf) .
But the accuracy I get with my implementation is about 84% - 85% with no augmentation for test data and about 88% with augmentation for test data which is absolutely far away from the results shown in the article - about 91% - 92% with no augmentation.

Here is my implementation of the ResNet:

```
class Block_of_net(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding):
    super(Block_of_net, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding)
    self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, 1, padding)

    for m in self.modules():
        if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
            nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight, mode='fan_out', nonlinearity='relu')

  def forward(self, x):
    x = F.relu(self.bn(self.conv1(x)))
    x = self.conv2(x)
    return x

# 3 blocks -- 6 convs -- of one map size with shortcuts after each block
# shorcut before non-linearity
class ResBlock(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
    super(ResBlock, self).__init__()
    self.in_ch = in_channels
    self.out_ch = out_channels
    self.proj = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, 1, 2)
    self.bn_proj = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
    if (in_channels == out_channels):
      self.bl1 = Block_of_net(in_channels, out_channels, 3, 1, 1)
    else:
      self.bl1 = Block_of_net(in_channels, out_channels, 3, 2, 1)
    self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
    self.bl2 = Block_of_net(out_channels, out_channels, 3, 1, 1)
    self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
    self.bl3 = Block_of_net(out_channels, out_channels, 3, 1, 1)
    self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)

  def forward(self, x):
    out = x

    if (self.in_ch == self.out_ch):
      shortcut1 = out.clone()
    else:
      shortcut1 = self.proj(out)
    out = self.bl1(out)
    out += shortcut1
    out = self.bn1(out)
    out = F.relu(out)

    shortcut2 = out.clone()
    out = self.bl2(out)
    out += shortcut2
    out = self.bn2(out)
    out = F.relu(out)

    shortcut3 = out.clone()
    out = self.bl3(out)
    out += shortcut3
    out = self.bn3(out)

    return out

class ResNet(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(ResNet, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 3, 1, 1)
    self.bn0 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
    self.res_block1 = ResBlock(16, 16)
    self.res_block2 = ResBlock(16, 32)
    self.res_block3 = ResBlock(32, 64)
    self.agP = nn.AvgPool2d(8)
    self.fc = nn.Linear(64, 10)

  def forward(self, x):
    out = F.relu(self.bn0(self.conv1(x)))

    out = F.relu(self.res_block1(out))
    out = F.relu(self.res_block2(out))
    out = F.relu(self.res_block3(out))

    out = self.agP(out)
    out = out.view(-1, 64)
    out = self.fc(out)

    return out
```

I use Adam as the optimizer with learning_rate = 0.0001, batch_size = 128, weight_decay = 0.0001 and CrossEntropyLoss.
The net learns for 300 epochs.

Here are the learning code and graphics of train_loss and val_acc:

```
epoch_loss = []
acc = []
train_time = []

for i in range(epochs):
  start_time = time.time()
  ep = 0
  net.train()
  for X_b, y_b in train_loader:
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    X_b = X_b.to(device)
    y_b = y_b.to(device)

    net_out = net(X_b)

    loss = loss_fn(net_out, y_b)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    with torch.no_grad():
        ep += loss.item()

  epoch_loss.append(round(ep, 3))

  correct = 0
  total = 0
  net.eval()
  with torch.no_grad():
    for X_b, y_b in test_loader2:
        X_b = X_b.to(device)
        y_b = y_b.to(device)

        net_out = net(X_b)
        loss = loss_fn(net_out, y_b)
        probs = F.softmax(net_out, dim=1)
        label = torch.argmax(probs, dim=1)
        correct += torch.sum(label==y_b).item()
        total = y_b.shape[0]
        break
    acc.append(round(correct/total,3))
  print("Epoch {0}: train_loss=={1} -- val_acc=={2}".format(i+1, ep, acc[-1]))
```

[Curves of training loss and validation accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwBr4.png)

For training I use simple augmentation: : 4 pixels are padded on each side,
and a 32×32 crop is randomly sampled from the padded image or its horizontal flip, also I apply randomly one of RandomRotation or RandomVerticalFlip.

So I need advice on how I can improve my implementation and where are the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Architecture is just one side of the story and the way you optimize it is the other side which is as important.
Try better hyper parameters and you'll definitely get higher accuracy.

What you can do is to use an already proven settings from other architectures that also have been trained on `CIFAR10` (preferably `ResNet`, but any other models will do and will give you a good starting point). Here is an example for a former [CIFAR10 sota](https://github.com/Coderx7/SimpleNet_Pytorch).

A side note:
Based on my experience in classification tasks (such as `CIFAR10`) `Adam` optimizer wont give you good accuracy unless you really try hard. I had much better luck with `Adadelta`, `SGD` and `RMSProp`.
Adam seems to be working fine when it comes to `GAN`s though, but in other scenarios I find it to always perform inferior compared to others.

Side note 2:
Try to use lower batch sizes, in practice you may fine batch sizes as small as 64 can give you pretty good results. Also nearly always try to start with a large learning rate and then gradually decrease it.